# Facebook login infinite repetition in React-native app

Tags: react-native, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

I created an app and implemented Facebook login using facebook sdk.
If the person who has logged in once logs in again, the question of whether to maintain the authority is repeatedly asked and the login is not possible.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your are intended to not have user already logged-in then
why don't you try `LoginManager.logOut()` before calling `LoginManager.logInWithPermissions` or `AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken()`